# Find pattern containing string not preceeded by other string

Tags: r, regex

I would like to use the `grepl` function in R to find if a string contains something, but on the condition that it is not preceeded by something else.

So for example say I wanted to find a string which includes the pattern `'xx'`, as long as it is not preceeded by `'yy'`. So:

`'123xx45'` world return `TRUE`

`'123yy4xx5'` would also return `TRUE` as the `'yy'` is not immediately preceding `'xx'`

However `'123yyxx45'` would return `FALSE`.

Please let me know if anything is unclear or you would like a better example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `grepl('(?<!yy)xx', c('123yy4xx5','123xx45','123yyxx45'), perl=TRUE)`?

Comment: Yep, that seems to work thanks! An brief explanation of what it is doing would be great though please

Comment: @user1165199 since Doctor Dan is busy I have found out it is a *zero-width negative lookbehind assertion*, which allows you to match something not preceeded by something else, in this case `yy`

Comment: @user1165199 Here's a [link about lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The key characters in a group are `(?=)` positive lookahead, `(?!)` (negative lookahead, `(?<=)` positive lookbehind and `(?<!)` negative lookbehind. It only works when you set `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: @SimonO101 Where did you find the information? I typically go to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing for text processing questions. I think it is a great resource, but does not have that level of detail.

Comment: @dayne I found it at the [**regex tutorial website**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) but it's also about 6 lines from the bottom of `?regex` in R!

Answer (score 3):

```
your.data <- c('123yy4xx5','123xx45','123yyxx45')
grepl("xx",your.data) & !grepl("yyxx",your.data)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```